# Change permalink structure hidden button edit

Tags: plugins, permalinks, filters, hooks

I created the function below that changes the permalink structure of posts in a specific category. Everything is working, but the button inside the post to edit the slug is gone.

Print edit button image

[image]

```
add_filter( 'post_link', 'idinheiro_custom_permalink', 10, 3 );
function idinheiro_custom_permalink( $permalink, $post ) {
    $category = get_the_category($post->ID);
    if (  !empty($category) && $category[0]->slug == "negocios" ) {
        $permalink = trailingslashit( home_url('/'. $category[0]->slug . '/' . $post->post_name .'/' ) );
    }
    return $permalink;
}
```

Comment: can you embed the image in the post using the provided tools instead of linking offsite?

Comment: @TomJNowell, done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`post_link` hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/post_link/) has a third parameter named `$leavename`:

> **$leavename**
> *(bool)* Whether to keep the post name.

So what that means is, if `$leavename` is `true`, then the post name/slug should be kept in the permalink and thus it needs to contain `%postname%` (or `%pagename%` for the `page` post type) instead of being replaced with the actual post slug (or something else).

Because if that placeholder is missing, the permalink will become non-editable on the post editing screen, therefore the Edit button is disabled. (See [`get_sample_permalink_html()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_sample_permalink_html/), specifically [this part](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.7.2/src/wp-admin/includes/post.php#L1459), and that function is the one which generates the post permalink editor)

So to fix the issue, define the variable: `function idinheiro_custom_permalink( $permalink, $post, $leavename )` and change the `'/' . $post->post_name .'/'` to:

```php
'/' . ( $leavename ? '%postname%' : $post->post_name ) .'/'
```

Comment: perfect. Thanks a lot!